# What is it that Lagrangian density with only bilinear terms always corresponds to free field theory?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, interactions

Is there an intuitive proof of this fact? (Maybe connected in some way to Central Limit Theorem?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because that way the Euler-Lagrange equations turn out to be linear and thus the superposition principle holds. Superposition principle means "free theory".