# Non-linearity and self-coupling of gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, lagrangian-formalism, interactions, non-linear-systems

I have heard that non-linearity of [Einstein's field equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) has to do with the fact that gravity self-couples. What does non-linearity have to do with self-coupling?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. In the action formalism a *linear* [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) corresponds to a *quadratic* action, i.e. an action which is *quadratic* in the dynamical field variables of the theory.
2. On the other hand, *self-coupling or interaction* terms in the action correspond to *cubic or higher* terms. Such terms leads to *non-linear* EL equations. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/600790/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/165805/2451) related Phys.SE posts.
3. In case of GR, the field variable is the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$. The [Einstein-Hilbert action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action) is *not* quadratic in $g_{\mu\nu}$, which leads to self-coupling/interaction and non-linear [EFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations).