# Electromagnetism, linearity and Feynman diagrams

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, feynman-diagrams, interactions, non-linear-systems

Currently I am reading Sean Carrol, general relativity. But a thing got me stuck in, I can't understand what he is talking about.

We are discussing the introduction to Einstein field equation, so he start talk about the linearity in Newtonian gravity and the non linearity in GR. But there is somethings I am missing:

> " (...) in GR the gravitational field couples to itself (...) A nice way to think about this is provided by Feynman diagrams (...) There is no diagram in which two photons exchange another photons between themselves, because electromagnetism is linear."

Particularly, I can't understand these citations.

First I am not sure what means a field to couples to itself, but I think it means it is linearity so the field in a point add linearity.

And I couldn't understand how does the fact that that the electromagnetism is linear imply that photons do not exchange photons between, I can see these both statements are right, but can't see the connection between them, so that one implies the other.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/170541/2451 and links therein.